# Professor wrote to me saying he supports my fellowship application to the committee

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, application

A professor I want to work with (at the university I applied to) informed that he is awaiting some funding news (for a project I had expressed interest in working with him on) and he also stated that he has highlighted my name to the fellowship committee.
Any idea what that means? Is that a positive development with regards to me getting an admit/fellowship?

Comment: This is all university/field specific. Is this a university fellowship, a teaching assistanship? Is the professor waiting to hear back on whether a grant was funded under which you will be supported? This is not clear in OP.

Comment: It is for a university fellowship and I get a priority consideration since I attended their recruitment event. 
Yes. Going by my in-person communication with him, that would likely be a project I can be funded under. He mentioned that if all goes well we may get the funding and that it is definitely a positive news. 
I am trying to make sense of his sentiment from the email. Is he being optimistic of my chances?

Comment: If it's a university-level competitive fellowship I doubt he has much say, other than the letter he could have submitted. I wouldn't get your hopes up just yet.

Answer (score 4):

It is positive certainly, but not definitive. It is just a progress report sent as a courtesy. He is being encouraging, but not making any commitments.

Of course, you need to go through the normal admissions process. This isn't a substitute for any formal procedures that are required. In US institutions admissions is handled by the university, not the individual professor. Funding may be under his control, however.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Thanks for the clarification. Hopefully my decent grades (3.6 CGPA) in masters (from a top school in my field), 3y of work experience and good projects will tilt the scale in my favor.
although I have no publications yet.. will that hurt my chances?